# SOLR performance slow after upgrade 8.11 to 9.0

Tags: solr

Due to a security issue with SOLR, I upgraded a group of nodes to v9.0.0. Also had to upgrade Java from 8 to 11 (minimum needed for SOLR v9). Since the update, the nodes under higher loads go zombie;

```
$ service solr stop
```

doesn't work, I have to kill -9 the process and then start the service again.

Things I've changed in the process of the upgrade:

- solr v8.11.1 -> solr v9.0.0
- java-1.8-openjdk -> java-11-openjdk
- for the core: solrconfig.xml arbitrary adjustments, like;

  - lucenmatchversion 8.11.1 -> 9.0
  - some older cache settings (solr.LRUCache for queryCache/documentCache no longer supported in v9, default is now CaffeineCache, for filterCache this was FastLRUCache)
  - queryresponsewriter xslt removed (not supported in v9)
- set log level to WARN because it looked like some default log setting was now producing more logs

I have 2 nodes behind a load balancer to distribute load across 2 server instances. After updating these instances with above changes, when I see load increase (more requests) at some point the service becomes unreachable on the nodes. The webinterface (when tried through a local connection) no longer works and the service does not respond to the normal stop signal in an ssh shell.

Things I've tried that didn't help:

- use openjdk-19 instead of 11
- use more memory; the instances run on systems with 16G memory with SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms5g -Xmx5g"; have also tried setting that to 8G, as well as leaving it at 5G but beefing up the server to 32G, but in all cases they still die.
- optimize the solr core (hadn't been optimized since january)

How to trouble shoot such a solr node that goes zombie? am I missing some obvious changes that would cause this degraded performance?

The core that's loaded on these nodes is close to 100M documents, size of the core (after optimize) is around 130G, to give an idea of scale.

Comment: What are the logs saying ? Did you reindex ? A full reindex is strongly recommended after a major version upgrade.

Comment: logs don't mention anything noteworthy; since its on WARN, I don't see anything past boot in the log. the gc log, not sure how to read those, also no warnings or oom messages or anything. I suppose that's part of the thing going zombie, that it even fails to log it. Didn't reindex, but the optimize into 20 segments should have taken care of any potentially slight differences there. A full reindex takes more than a week, so trying to put that off if possible.

Comment: Ok, also have a look at the system logs, if there is an oom or something as critical as that, it would only be logged at this level.